# Firebase query where field doesn't exists

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have requirement where i have to query `Users` those `permitted` field not exsists.

**My Approach to query data**

```js
const waitListQuery = query(usersColRef, where('permitted', '==', null)
```

but it's always return empty array `[]`

**Example DataSet:-**

```js
[  {..., permitted: true }, { ..., permitted: false }, { ... } ]
```

**Any idea how to make query work?**

Comment: Is this working ?:- where('permitted', '==', FieldValue.delete())

Comment: `- deleteField() can only be used with update() and set()`

Comment: Firestore doesn't have queries for fields that don't exist. Such a query would not scale in the way the Firestore requires.